# z-index - fixed, absolute, relative

Tags: css

the z-index in "div.dialog" doesnt seem to influ the layer index? the "div.dialog" div has to be on top of everything

EDIT:

- `div.dialog_bg` has to be in the background
- `#topfix` has to be on top of that
- `div.dialog` has to be on top of everything

code...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <body style="margin:0px">
        <style>
            #topfix {
                position:fixed;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                width:100%;
                height:130px;
                z-index:1;
                background:#ff0000;
            }

            #div_dialog {
                position:relative;
                z-index:1;
            }

            div.dialog {
                position:absolute;
                background:#ffffff;
                border:1px solid #000000;
                width:400px;
                height:300px;
                top:50px;
                left:100px;
                z-index:99; // doesnt seem to influ the layer index
            }

            div.dialog_bg {
                position:absolute;
                background:#ffff00;
                width:100%;
                height:500px;
                opacity:0.3;
            }
        </style>

        <div id="div_dialog">
            <div class="dialog_bg"></div>
            <div class="dialog">test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test</div>
        </div>
        <div id="topfix">
            topfix
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you need to give its parent `#div_dialog` at least `z-index: 2` because the z-index is relative to its parent and `dialog` is the only child of `#div_dialog`.

Also `z-index: 1` for `#div_dialog` isn't enough because `#topfix` comes after it in HTML and will be placed over `#div_dialog`.

**EDIT**

So regarding your "new" you have to give

```
#div_dialog { 
     position: absolute; 
     z-index: 9999; 
 }
.dialog_bg { 
   z-index: 1; 
}
.dialog { 
   z-index: 2; 
}
```

Comment: I have made a bit change in the description